# Openweathermap API won't work outside of VS Code

Tags: javascript, api, visual-studio-code, openweathermap

I'm still new to API's but for the life of me I can't figure out why this app works fine when viewing it on live-server in Visual Studio Code, but won't work anywhere else!

I'm still SUPER new to coding, and this is my first time using API's. Do I need to create a CRUD operation? 
I posted the js file below.

```
let appId = 'fa19585e62ed3b8595ff01cd2670cfd2'
let units = 'imperial'
let searchMethod;

function getSearchMethod(searchTerm) {
    if(searchTerm.length === 5 && Number.parseInt(searchTerm) + "" === searchTerm)
        searchMethod = 'zip'
    else
        searchMethod = 'q'
}

function searchWeather(searchTerm) {
    getSearchMethod(searchTerm)
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?${searchMethod}=${searchTerm}&APPID=${appId}&units=${units}`).then(result => {
        return result.json()
    }).then(result => {
        init(result)
    })
}

function init(resultFromServer) {
    switch (resultFromServer.weather[0].main) {
        case 'Clear':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("clear.jpg")'
            break;

        case 'Clouds':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("cloudy.jpg")'
            break;

        case 'Rain':
        case 'Drizzle':
        case 'Mist':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("rain.jpg")'
            break;

        case 'Thunderstorm':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("storm.jpg")'
            break;

        case 'Snow':
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("snow.jpg")'
            break  

        default:
            break;
    }

    let weatherDescriptionHeader = document.getElementById('weatherDescriptionHeader')
    let temperatureElement = document.getElementById('temperature')
    let humidityElement = document.getElementById('humidity')
    let windSpeedElement = document.getElementById('windSpeed')
    let cityHeader = document.getElementById('cityHeader')
    let weatherIcon = document.getElementById('documentIconImg')

    weatherIcon.src = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + resultFromServer.weather[0].icon + '.png'

    let resultDescription = resultFromServer.weather[0].description
    weatherDescriptionHeader.innerText = resultDescription.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + resultDescription.slice(1)

    temperatureElement.innerHTML = Math.floor(resultFromServer.main.temp) + '&#176 '
    windSpeedElement.innerHTML = 'Wind at ' + Math.floor(resultFromServer.wind.speed) + ' m/s'
    cityHeader.innerHTML = resultFromServer.name
    humidityElement.innerHTML = 'Humidity levels at: ' + resultFromServer.main.humidity + '%'

    setPositionForWeatherInfo()
}

function setPositionForWeatherInfo() {
    let weatherContainer = document.getElementById('weatherContainer')
    let weatherContainerHeight = weatherContainer.clientHeight
    let weatherContainerWidth = weatherContainer.clientWidth

    weatherContainer.style.left = `calc(50% - ${weatherContainerWidth/2}px)`
    weatherContainer.style.top =  `calc(50% - ${weatherContainerHeight/1.3}px)`
    weatherContainer.style.visibility = 'visible'
}

document.getElementById('searchBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchInput').value
    if(searchTerm)
        searchWeather(searchTerm)
})
```

Comment: It would helpful if you could also provide the error message you receive from the browser when you try to run it outside of VS Code.

Comment: Thank you for the obvious check the console. Blocked loading mixed active content “http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=72227&APPID=fa19585e62ed3b8595ff01cd2670cfd2&units=imperial” is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have some issues with your code because you're asking for data over `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`

Refer to the following [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) page:

> If your website delivers HTTPS pages, all active mixed content delivered via HTTP on this pages will be blocked by default. Consequently, your website may appear broken to users (if iframes or plugins don't load, etc.). Passive mixed content is displayed by default, but users can set a preference to block this type of content, as well.

Answer (score -1):

Change URL in `searchWeather` from `http://api.openweathermap.org/...` to `https://api.openweathermap.org/...`

Comment: Already explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: The cause was explained, but no solution provided - once Open Weather served only http to freemium users, now it's https for all